# Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property socialsharing of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK with Cordova API. I have added the Social Sharing Plugin. I have added the plugin into the IDE from project settings and when i use the plugin by running following command: `window.window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Hello");` It gives a type error exception below 
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined`. I have also tried the examples given in social sharing plugin page but none of them worked for me. Intel XDK has automatically written the config.xml file and here are the contents of it

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:intelxdk="http://xdk.intel.com/ns/v1" id="xdk.intel.blank.ad.template" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="1">
<!--This file is generated by the Intel XDK. Do not edit this file as your edits will be lost.           -->
<!--To change the contents of this file, see the documentation on the intelxdk.config.additions.xml file.-->
<intelxdk:version value="1.0"/>
<intelxdk:cordova-cli version="4.1.2"/>
<name>My App</name>
<description>Template to develop a Cordova mobile web app using the App Designer UI editor.</description>
<author>Intel XDK</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Media" intelxdk:value="org.apache.cordova.media" intelxdk:version="0.2.15"/>
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="File" intelxdk:value="org.apache.cordova.file" intelxdk:version="1.3.2"/>
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Device" intelxdk:value="org.apache.cordova.device" intelxdk:version="0.2.13"/>
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Social Sharing" intelxdk:value="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git"/>
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="SocialSharing*" intelxdk:value="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10"/>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<!--creationInfo:{"src":"appDesigner","projectTypeName":"com.intel.xdk.projecttype.jsapp"}-->
<preference name="debuggable" value="false"/></widget>
```

I am using Cordova 4.1 with Intel XDK. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Real device or emulator?

Comment: Tried it on real device as well nothing will show up when i click share button. Moreover i have debugged my code with Intel XDK on my smartphone and on console it shows me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head against the wall with this error for 24 hours, but I finally figured it out. After poring over the issues section on github, I found a place [where the developer mentioned](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/236#issuecomment-64527497) that **window.plugins.socialsharing will *always* by undefined in the phonegap app**. Once I ran and built locally with a USB cable (*not* using the downloadable cloud-based phonegap app), it worked beautifully on the first try.

On a side note, the developer seems amazingly responsive and friendly and helpful. If you're really getting stuck on this and my suggestion didn't help, I'd recommend perusing the [issues section on github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues) to see if you can find a similar problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me. 
Remove `var cordova = require('cordova');`
and add

```
var cordova = window.cordova;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel real stupid about this, but I spent 4 hours to figure out that I had somehow deleted the

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" version="5.4.0" />
```

from my config.xml file....

BTW I have no problem using this plugin when building the app using build.phonegap.com.

Answer (score -3):

Did you include SocialSharing.js in your project and load it like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
```

Make sure the S are upper case in the file name too...

Comment: Yes i did but the point is that window.plugins is undefined so it will not be able to find window.plugins.socialshare. I don't know how to fix it. Please tell me if you know anything

Answer (score -3):

make sure you installed the plugin

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git`